# Using EDIMAX EW-7811UN WiFi Dongle and Mouse freezes RPi

Tags: raspbian

Using the EDIMAX EW-7811UN WiFi Dongle and Mouse freezes RPi, i cannot move the mouse even if i replug the mouse, it doesn't work, but the RPi work normally when i'm plugging the mouse only.

For power i'm using samsung galaxy S2 Charger(700 mA).

I'm using RPi REV 2.0

Any Help please

Comment: you should use a better power supply. you should use a better power supply. you should use a better power supply. you should use a better power supply. you should use a better power supply. you should use a better power supply. you should use a better power supply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is the wireless isn't getting enough power to function.  Try a power supply in the 1 amp range.

See http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/ What are the power requirements?